# htaccess rule to redirect calls to a subfolder of a different folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a website (**A**) in **mydomain.com** that uses CakePHP, and it's located in */path/to/sites/mywebsiteA*.

Now, I'm setting up a new site (**B**) that will also use CakePHP, and will be located in */path/to/sites/mywebsiteB*.

The challenge comes because I want the URL for website B to be **mydomain.com/websiteB**. This URL should open the index file of **Website B**. And then, any link of the form **mydomain.com/websiteB/*** should be processed by **website B** as well, while any other link for **mydomain.com** should be processed by **website A**.

Currently **website A** has the following code in its root htaccess file (this is for CakePHP to work properly):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Website B** also has that same code in its root htaccess file since it's also a CakePHP file like I mention above.

How would I modify **Website B**'s htaccess file in order to accomplish what I'm trying?

**Examples for clarification**

**- mydomain.com/contact:** should call */contact* in **website A**'s folder (basically as if there was no special htaccess rule)

**- mydomain.com/users/index:** same as above (call */users/index*)

**- mydomain.com/websiteB/campaign:** should call */campaign* in **website B**'s  folder

**- mydomain.com/websiteB/campaign/exec:** should call */campaign/exec* in  **website B**'s folder

**- mydomain.com/websiteB/users/create:** should call */users/create* in **website B**'s folder

Comment: Q1: Should `mydomain.com/abcd` be routed to `mydomain.com/websiteA/abcd`? Q2: What are example URLs for accessing `websiteA`?

Comment: @anubhava I added a few examples to clarify your questions, thanks!